# How do you make the TopMost form the only clickable form until its closed?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make it so that the login form pops up and the window behind that cannot be accessed until the login form is closed.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a modal form.  So use `form.ShowDialog()` instead of `form.Show()`